# Discord Unity SDK showing still playing, yet it is closed

Tags: unity-game-engine, discord

So i am writing a game and everything was fine until i stopped the game in unity editor but it still shows me as playing it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Discord;

public class DiscordController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Discord.Discord discord;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        discord = new Discord.Discord(764652301289259078, (System.UInt64)Discord.CreateFlags.Default);
        var activityManager = discord.GetActivityManager();
        var activity = new Discord.Activity
        {
            State = "Beta",
            Details = "- In Devolpment DM me for a beta if you want"
        };
        activityManager.UpdateActivity(activity, (res) =>
        {
            if (res == Discord.Result.Ok)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Everything is fine!");
            }
        });
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        discord.RunCallbacks();
    }
}
```

please help its annoying.
thanks for reading,

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, unity editor is still runnning the code when i stop it.